# Why is "lately" usually used in a perfect tense sentence?

Tags: tense

When you look up "lately tense", google gives the top result from [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/lately)

> I haven't heard from him **lately**.
>
> **Lately** is usually used with a **perfect tense** of the verb.Look also at
>   the idioms be too late (at the adjective) and too late (at the
>   adverb).

But I want to know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present perfect tense can be used when we describe our experience up to the present.  Examples:

> I **have eaten** raw fish.
>
> I **have been** to France.

"Lately" is normally used with these kind of sentences, to talk about *recent* experience:

> **Have** you **eaten** raw fish lately?
>
> **Have** you **been** to France lately?
>
> She **hasn't been** coming in to work on time lately. I wonder what's wrong?

It is possible to use "lately" with the simple present or simple past, but it feels more natural to use it with the present perfect, to suggest the experience could have happened any time up to the present moment.